# Performance issues on Samsung Smart TV

Tags: javascript, samsung-smart-tv

I'm currently developing a web application in Samsung Smart TV IDE, I've been testing it on the IDE emulator and it works fine. But when I try it on a real TV (Model: UE32H4500AW), the performance slow down a lot, it takes a lot to process the input events when it needs to translate a huge amount of simple divs.
Here's the code where it slow down:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/API/Widget.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/API/TVKeyValue.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/API/Plugin.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            *{
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                border: 0;
                color: white;
                background: black;
            }
             body{
                overflow: hidden;
             }
             #wrapper {
                 position: relative;
                width: 70vw;
                height: 70vw;
                overflow: hidden;
             }
             #EPG-channel-wrapper {
                vertical-align: top;
                width: 20%;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                display: inline-block;
            }           
            .EPG-channel {
                height: 50px;
                width: auto;
                padding: 15px;
                border: 2px solid white;
                white-space: nowrap;
                overflow: hidden;
                vertical-align: top;
                text-overflow: ellipsis;
            }
            .EPG-channel-title-wrapper {
                display: inline-block;
                vertical-align: top;
            }
            .EPG-channel-title {
                vertical-align: top;
            }
            #EPG-program-wrapper {
                vertical-align: top;
                display: inline-block;
                position: relative;
                width: 75%;
                left: 3%;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                overflow-x: hidden;
            }
            .EPG-channel-programs {
                height: 84px;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                border: 2px solid yellow
            }
            .EPG-program {
                border: 2px solid cyan;
                height: 100%;
                width: 30%;
                box-sizing: border-box; 
                display: inline-block;
            }
            .EPG-program-context {
                display: inline-block;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var widgetAPI = new Common.API.Widget();
            var tvKey = new Common.API.TVKeyValue();
            var Main = {};
            Main.onLoad = function()
            {
                // Enable key event processing
                document.onkeydown = Main.keyDown(event);
                widgetAPI.sendReadyEvent();
                Main.loadDivs();
            };
            Main.loadDivs = function() {
                var addChannels = [];
                var addPrograms = [];
                var width = 0;
                for(var i = 0; i< 140; i++){
                    addChannels[addChannels.length] = "<div class='EPG-channel'>";
                    addChannels[addChannels.length] = "<img alt='' src='' class='EPG-channel-img'>";
                    addChannels[addChannels.length] = "<div class='EPG-channel-title-wrapper'><div class='EPG-channel-title'>Test " + i +" </div></div></div>";
                    addPrograms[addPrograms.length] = "<div class='EPG-channel-programs'>";
                    for( var j = 0; j< 100; j++){
                        width = 200;
                        addPrograms[addPrograms.length] = "<div class='EPG-program' style='width:"+width+"px'>";
                        addPrograms[addPrograms.length] = "<div class='EPG-program-title'>Test program "+ i + " - " + j + " </div>";
                        addPrograms[addPrograms.length] = "<div class='EPG-program-duration'>00.00 - 00.00</div></div>";
                    };
                    addPrograms[addPrograms.length] = "</div>";
                };
                document.getElementById("EPG-channel-wrapper").innerHTML = addChannels.join('');
                document.getElementById("EPG-program-wrapper").innerHTML = addPrograms.join('');
            };
            Main.translate = 0;
            Main.keyDown = function(event)
            {
                var keyCode = event.keyCode;

                switch(keyCode)
                {
                    case tvKey.KEY_LEFT:
                        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("EPG-program");
                        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
                            elements[i].style.display = "";
                        }
                        break;
                    case tvKey.KEY_RIGHT:
                        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("EPG-program");
                        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
                            elements[i].style.display = "none";
                        }
                        break;
                    case tvKey.KEY_UP:
                        var translate = --Main.translate * document.getElementsByClassName("EPG-channel")[0].offsetHeight;
                        document.getElementById("EPG-channel-wrapper").style["-webkit-transform"] = "translate(0, -"+translate+"px)";
                        document.getElementById("EPG-program-wrapper").style["-webkit-transform"] = "translate(0, -"+translate+"px)";
                        break;
                    case tvKey.KEY_DOWN:
                        var translate = ++Main.translate * document.getElementsByClassName("EPG-channel")[0].offsetHeight;
                        document.getElementById("EPG-channel-wrapper").style["-webkit-transform"] = "translate(0, -"+translate+"px)";
                        document.getElementById("EPG-program-wrapper").style["-webkit-transform"] = "translate(0, -"+translate+"px)";
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            };
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onkeydown="Main.keyDown(event)" onload="Main.onLoad();">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="EPG-channel-wrapper"></div>
            <div id="EPG-program-wrapper"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When right key is pressed, it hide all the programs and the performance works fine.

Is there any memory leak I might be missing or other way to translate that amount of divs more efficiently?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Performance issues tend to be implementation specific. What works faster in one environment may be slower in another. We can offer alternative implementations, but which is faster on the target hardware can only be determined by running it on the target hardware.

Comment: `when it needs to translate a huge amount of simple divs` your code only "translates" two divs?

Comment: @JaromandaX there are 14000 divs between those two divs, if this amount is reduced, the performance improves.

Comment: @RobG, is there any way to move divs, besides -webkit-translate, top, or basic scroll? I have alredy test those ways.

Comment: 14,000 divs is an awful lot of divs, I can't imagine why you're generating so many. If reducing the number increases performance, I'd concentrate on modifying the layout to reduce them to a minimum.